# Wrong lex state when parsing multiple files

Tags: c, bison, yacc, lex

I am trying to parse two files with win flex and bison, but I am encountering a problem where lex is not in the state I am expecting.  In the lex file:

```
include[ \t]+\" { BEGIN(include_state); }
<include_state>([^\\\"\n]|\\.)+ {
    yyin = fopen(yytext, "r");
    if (!yyin) {
        printf("Error opening include file: %s\n", yytext);
        return 1;
    }
    yypush_buffer_state(yy_create_buffer(yyin, YY_BUF_SIZE, yyscanner),
        yyscanner);
    BEGIN(INITIAL);
}
<include_state>\"[ \t]*";" { BEGIN(INITIAL); }
<<EOF>> {
    yypop_buffer_state(yyscanner);
    if (!YY_CURRENT_BUFFER)
        yyterminate();
}
```

The first file being parsed includes the second file as follows:

```
include "hello.txt";
```

What happens when parsing is that the second file ("hello.txt") is parsed OK with no problems, but there is a problem when returning to the first file.  The quote and semi colon at the end of the line are read, but lex is in the INITIAL state.  So lex is not matching on the rule that I'm expecting it to match on.  I know this for sure because if I add the following rule (it matches):

```
<INITIAL>\"[ \t]*";" { printf("Right matching, wrong state.\n"); return 1; }
```

Why does it not return to the include_state and how can I fix this?

Comment: I answered this in your previous question: The start condition is *not* part of the buffer state, so you need to manage it separately. In this case, the simplest solution would be to read the closing `"` before doing the include.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it goes to INITIAL because that's what you tell it to do after calling *yypush_buffer_state()*. How is it ever going to match the second `<include_state>` if you do that? What happens if you delete that state change?

Comment: I think your diagnosis of the problem is correct. What happens if the `BEGIN(INITIAL);` is removed, though, is that the include file content is all read in the `include_state`, which gives problems because the body of the file probably needs to be read in the initial state.  I'm not sure if the EOF rule could reset the state to `include_state` (when the EOF is for one of the included files).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That sounds reasonable. Maybe it's an alternative not to use states but upon encountering an #include statement push the current yyin aside, deal with the include file contents, and upon EOF pop back yyin and continue. Or look at how contemporary C preprocessors deal with the problem :-)

Comment: @Jens: That won't work, because the current buffer is not synchronized; it's already got future data in it. Just changing `yyin` won't take effect until the end of the buffer is reached. Forcing a change will discard the data read. That's why `(f)lex` provides buffers and buffer stacks; you should use them. Also, there is absolutely no issue with setting the start condition whenever you want to, even in an EOF rule, because it is *global*, not part of the buffer state. (In a pure lexer, it is part of the scanner state. But there is only one per scanner.)

Comment: You (Jonathan Leffler and Jens) are both right.  I set the state to include_state upon EOF and it worked fine.  (Update) @Jens what is wrong with my new approach?

Comment: @tyebillion Nothing is wrong if it meets your requirements :-)

Comment: Sorry I meant @rici: what is wrong with my new approach?

Comment: @tyebillion: Nothing, if it works for you and you understand how it works. It just seems like a lot of work to ignore a quote.

Answer (score 1):

The start condition is *global*. It is not part of the buffer state. Pushing and popping the buffer state *do not* change it. You have to manage it yourself.

You could restore the start condition to `include_state` after you do the `yypop_buffer_state`. You could even keep your own stack of lexer states along side of the stack of buffers. But the simplest solution seems to be reading the closing punctuation in the `#include` statement before performing the `#include`, so that you are always in `INITIAL` state when changing buffers:

```
<include_state>[^\n"]+\" {
    yytext[yyleng - 1] = 0; // Get rid of the close quote.
    yyin = fopen(yytext, "r");
    if (!yyin) {
        printf("Error opening include file: %s\n", yytext);
        return 1;
    }
    yypush_buffer_state(yy_create_buffer(yyin, YY_BUF_SIZE, yyscanner),
                        yyscanner);
    BEGIN(INITIAL);
}
<include_state>.|\n   { /* Handle syntax error in #include */ }
```